# Do I have to swap IP sets, or can I add/remove on the fly?

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall, ipset

I was wondering about the semantics of [`ipset(8)`](http://ipset.netfilter.org/).

Is it possible to add a rule matching a set to `iptables` and then manipulate the set, or can I only create a set and swap it for an older set in order to apply it to an `iptables` rule matching the name? **I.e. can I add/remove to/from an IP set ad hoc, or can I exchange whole sets while the sets are in active use?**

---

The reason I ask is this is as follows. Say I create a set

```
ipset create PCs hash:ip
ipset add PCs 1.1.1.1
ipset add PCs 2.2.2.2
```

... et cetera. And a rule that allows access to HTTP:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m set --set PCs src -j ACCEPT
```

What happens when I run:

```
ipset add PCs 3.3.3.3
```

will the `iptables` rule now take immediate effect for IP 3.3.3.3 as well?

I saw it's possible to use `-j SET --add-set ...` to manipulate IP sets ad hoc from within `iptables` rules. This makes me think it should work to manipulate a set at any given point.

However, the `ipset` project site seems to suggest that swapping a new (adjusted) set for another is the better alternative. Be it via `ipset swap` or via `ipset restore -!`.

Can anyone shed light on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add and remove IPs to your already defined sets on the fly.  This is one of the ideas behind IPsets: if this wasn't possible, the whole `set` extension of `iptables` wouldn't make much sense.

The primary goal of `ipset` was to enable you to define (also dynamically) classes of matches (e.g. for dynamically blacklisting malicious hosts without the need to magically add one rule for every single host).

*excerpt from the [ipset homepage](http://netfilter.org/projects/ipset/index.html)*

> - store multiple IP addresses or port numbers and match against the collection by iptables at one swoop
> - dynamically update iptables rules against IP addresses or ports without performance penalty
> - express complex IP address and ports based rulesets with one single iptables rule and benefit from the speed of IP sets

Comment: Thanks. There's one thing I disagree with, though. Actually it would still make perfect sense, even if a set could not be changed. Picking a set of individual IPs instead of a full subnet, adding huge quantities of IPs/networks/host:port entries ... those are not only cumbersome, but `iptables` has real limits there. Not to mention the speed improvements `ipset` can give you over individual rules. Do you have a source for the statement from the last paragraph, btw? +1 for now.

Comment: Not definite, but that's what I understood the idea of `ipset` like. ;)  The `ipset` [homepage](http://netfilter.org/projects/ipset/index.html) states three use cases, first two being matching against huge lists (as you mentioned), second one being dynamically updating rules (as I mentioned).